# Group inputs in control-group with Formtastic-Boostrap

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, formtastic

I'm using Formtastic with the [Bootstrap formbuilder](https://github.com/mjbellantoni/formtastic-bootstrap/). I can't figure out how to add more than one inputs into a control group, as such:

[image: 3 inputs next to each other]

The logical thing for me would be to do the following (I'm using HAML):

```
= f.inputs do
      = f.input :city, :input_html=>{:class=>'input-small'}, :label=>false, :placeholder=>'City'
      = f.input :state, :input_html=>{:class=>'input-small'}, :label=>false, :placeholder=>'State'
      = f.input :zip, :input_html=>{:class=>'input-small'}, :label=>false, :placeholder=>'Zip'
```

But that simply groups the controls in a fieldset.

I don't see anything in the documentation for this, and Google hasn't helped much either. Can anybody help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using the default Rails form builder for areas where I needed inputs next to each other.